# How to use multiple instance of repr()

Tags: python, repr

So I have my program printing out the first portion of what I would like, but now for the second menu option I would like it to look up the Pokemon by name, and then for that pokemon specifically fill out what the pokedex entry for it is. My thought would be to use multiple instances of repr() but so far that hasn't really worked for me.

edit: I decided to try a search method using:

```
def lookup_by_name(pokedex, name):
            for i in pokedex:
                    search: name
                    if i == search:
                            print(i)
                            print("yes")
```

but when I do this I get the error "local variable 'search' referenced before assignment"

```
import string
def print_menu():
        print("1. Print Pokedex")
        print("2. Print Pokemon by Name")
        print("3. Print Pokemon by Number")
        print("4. Count Pokemon with Type")
        print("5. Print Average Pokemon Combat Points")
        print("6. Quit")


        return print_menu
def print_pokedex(pokedex):
        print(pokedex)
def lookup_by_name(pokedex, name):
        print(Pokemon.print_pokemon_name(Pokemon))


class Pokemon:
        def __init__(self, name, number, combat_points, types):
                self.number = number
                self.name = name
                self.combat_points = combat_points
                self.types = types

        def __repr__(self):
                return "Number: {}, Name: {}, CP: {}, Types: {}, \n".format(str(self.number), self.name, str(self.combat_points), str(self.types).strip("[]',"))

        def print_pokemon_name(self):
                return "Number: {}, Name: {}, CP: {}, Types: {}, \n".format(str(self.number), self.name, str(self.combat_points), str(self.types).strip("[]',"))







# ---------------------------------------
# Do not change anything below this line
# ---------------------------------------

def create_pokedex(filename):
    pokedex = []
    file = open(filename, "r")

    for pokemon in file:
        pokelist = pokemon.strip().split(",")
        number = int(pokelist[0])               # number
        name = pokelist[1]                      # name
        combat_points = int(pokelist[2])        # hit points
        types = []
        for position in range(3, len(pokelist)):
            types += [pokelist[position]]       # type
        pokedex += [Pokemon(name, number, combat_points, types)]

    file.close()
    return pokedex

# ---------------------------------------

def get_choice(low, high, message):
    legal_choice = False
    while not legal_choice:
        legal_choice = True
        answer = input(message)
        for character in answer:
            if character not in string.digits:
                legal_choice = False
                print("That is not a number, try again.")
                break 
        if legal_choice:
            answer = int(answer)
            if (answer < low) or (answer > high):
                legal_choice = False
                print("That is not a valid choice, try again.")
    return answer

# ---------------------------------------

def main():
    pokedex = create_pokedex("pokedex.txt")
    choice = 0
    while choice != 6:
        print_menu()
        choice = get_choice(1, 6, "Enter a menu option: ")
        if choice == 1:    
            print_pokedex(pokedex)
        elif choice == 2:
            name = input("Enter a Pokemon name: ").lower()
            lookup_by_name(pokedex, name)
        elif choice == 3:
            number = get_choice(1, 1000, "Enter a Pokemon number: ")
            lookup_by_number(pokedex, number)
        elif choice == 4:
            pokemon_type = input("Enter a Pokemon type: ").lower()
            total_by_type(pokedex, pokemon_type)
        elif choice == 5:
            average_hit_points(pokedex)
        elif choice == 6:
            print("Thank you.  Goodbye!")
        print()

# ---------------------------------------

main()
```

Comment: Hi @CrockPocket.  Welcome to SO.  Why are you creating a new variable 'search'.  Instead, you can directly compare (i == name)?

Comment: There's a lot of confusing stuff in your code, but I'd guess you might want `if i.name == name`?

Comment: @Venkat_The_Mufasa you were right, I was adding unnecessary stuff in there, thank you!

Comment: @Blckknght that was totally the way to do it, thank you!